# Include map input to the aws step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

Currently I have a yaml file which includes different states in the Step function that runs different checks and returns pass or fail output

code Snippet:

```
Comment: Check all steps
StartAt: Check A

States:
  Check A:
    Comment: Verifies that A is done
    Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:checkA",
    Next: Check B

  Check B:
    Comment:Verifies that B is done
      Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:checkB"
    Next: Check C

  Check C:
     Comment:Verifies that C is done
      Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:checkC"
    ResultPath: "$.ValidatedResults"
    End: true
```

How can I modify this step function to accept an input map such that it only executes those States with boolean true

```
"OnlyVerify": {
    "Check A": true,
    "Check B": false
    "Check C": true
   
}
```

And if `OnlyVerify` map is not specified as input to the Step function, it should run all the Checks.(True for all checks by default)

Expected Output

```
{
"OnlyVerify": {
    "Check A": true,
    "Check B": false
    "Check C": true
   
},
"ValidatedResults": {
    "Check A": PASS,
    "Check C": PASS
}


}
```

Appreciate any guidance here

Comment: Can you provide an example JSON structure of what you expect/want `$.ValidatedResults` to be?

Comment: @deric4 any suggestions on how selective checks can be implemented based on the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest playing with the logic a bit in the Workflow Studio, but something like this should get you most of the way there:

[image: example workflow]

If the lambda function used to do the checking can be refactored to handle any of [A, B, C, ...] then that would enable making the step function definition much "cleaner" by leveraging a Map State, rather than a parallel state.

Comment: In this case, checkAskipped, checkBskipped and CheckCSkipped states are going to be the same 

`SkipState:`
  `Type: Pass`
 `End: true`

Can they share the common skip state instead of having separate pass state in each branch?

Comment: @raosa unfortunately no, its one of the most annoying things lol  

> Put another way, states in a branch’s "States" field can transition only to each other, and no state outside of that "States" field can transition into it.  

https://states-language.net/#parallel-state